# why changing metric doesn't impact route selection

Tags: route

I have the following output for my default route :

```
Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask        Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.167.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp1s0
192.168.167.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp1s0
```

And here the selected route to 8.8.8.8. Until here, nothing extraordinary.

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.167.1 (192.168.167.1)  0.326 ms  0.465 ms  0.527 ms
 2  192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)  1.409 ms  1.422 ms  1.429 ms
```

When I activate the VPN, the route becomes :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.13       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.167.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp1s0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.13       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.13       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.13       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 tun0
192.168.167.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp1s0
213.246.56.21   192.168.167.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp1s0
```

Whatever value I set for tun0 metric :

```
sudo ifmetric tun0 3000
```

route -n output :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.13       128.0.0.0       UG    3000   0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.167.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp1s0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.13       255.255.255.255 UGH   3000   0        0 tun0
10.8.0.13       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    3000   0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.13       128.0.0.0       UG    3000   0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     3000   0        0 tun0
192.168.167.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp1s0
213.246.56.21   192.168.167.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp1s0
```

The selected route is always going through interface tun0 :

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1)  28.510 ms  33.924 ms  33.941 ms
 2  ik056002.ikoula.com (213.246.56.2)  33.960 ms
...
```

Why ??

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes are process from most specific to least specific, if there are two routes with the same level of specificity, only then is the metric checked.

You are using the `route -n` format, which kinda sucks IMO, it would look better and be more obvious if you did an `ip route show`, which has output probably looks like this for you.

```
default via 192.168.167.1 dev enp1s0 metric 100
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.13 dev tun0 metric 3000
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.13 dev tun0 metric 3000
...
```

The two routes have different specificity, so the metric is irrelevant.  The `/1` is more specific (by 1 bit) then the `/0` route.

When you are looking at the `route -n` output, you must remember that you have to consider both the 1st and 3rd columns.  A route is the network address **and** the mask.